# Tablesorter plugin not sorting second TBody

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I can't get the second TBody to sort at all what am I doing wrong? The first tbody works correctly but the second one does nothing. If that can't work which I know it should. Then I would need the sort options to always sort by type then by whatever option the user selects. Sort of like a group by then sort.

```
enter code here<table id="response-table" width="100%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" class="tablesorter table">
                                <thead>
                                <tr style="border-bottom: thin solid black;">
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Date modified</th>
                                    <th>Type</th>
                                    <th>Size</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                @foreach ( $folders as $folder)
                                    <tr class="document folder"  id="{{ $folder['id'] }}" style="border: none;">
                                        <td class="no-borders" width="60%"><i class="fa fa-folder text-warning"></i>&nbsp;{{ $folder['name'] }}</td>
                                        <td class="no-borders"><small>{{ date_format(date_create($folder['updated_at'])," m/d/Y  h:i a") }}</small></td>
                                        <td class="no-borders"><small>File folder</small></td>
                                        <td class="no-borders"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                @endforeach
                                </tbody>
                                <tbody>
                                @foreach ( $files as $file)
                                    <tr class="document file"  id="{{ $file['id'] }}" style="border: none;">
                                        <td class="no-borders" width="60%"><i class="fa fa-file text-primary"></i>&nbsp;{{ $file['name'] }}</td>
                                        <td class="no-borders"><small>{{ date_format(date_create($file['updated_at'])," m/d/Y  h:i a") }}</small></td>
                                        <td class="no-borders"><small>{{ $file['extension'] }}</small></td>
                                        <td class="no-borders">{{ $file['bytes'] }}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                @endforeach
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the original tablesorter (v2.0.5) from tablesorter.com, it only supports the sorting of the first tbody ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/1527/)).

To get tablesorter to sort multiple tbodies, you'll need to switch to my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) - [here is a demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-multiple-tbodies.html).

```
$(function() {

  $("table").tablesorter({
    theme : 'blue',
    // class name added to tbodies where the content is ignored
    cssInfoBlock : "tablesorter-no-sort"
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you also tell me how to get the sorting arrows to display in the table header?

Comment: Pick & set the [`theme` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#theme), and load the css.